# Convert create.bspline.basis((rangval,nbasis,norder=norder,breaks=breaks) in R to BSpline(t, c, degree) in Python

Tags: python, r

I am trying to convert the function `create.bspline.basis(rangval,nbasis,norder=norder,breaks=breaks)`  from R to Python.

I have tried using the BSpline(t, c , degree) function from scipy.interpolate but cannot seem the get the same results as I got in R.

**Here is my R code:**

```
library('fda')

df <- read.csv('data.csv', header = T)

df <- df[,1]        # convert data frame to vector. Vector has a length of 1941.

rangval <- c(1, length(df))

breaks = seq(1,length(df),length.out=length(df)/60)

norder = 6

nbasis = length(breaks) - 2 + norder

bbasis = create.bspline.basis(rangval,nbasis,norder=norder,breaks=breaks)

plot(bbasis)
```

[image: basis_plot]

**Here is my Python code:**

from scipy.interpolate import BSpline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

import math

#### Load Data files as data frames:

df = pd.read_csv('RData\Data.csv')

#### Convert data frames to arrays:

df = df.to_numpy()

breaks = np.linspace(1, (len(df)), math.ceil(len(df)/60))

k = math.ceil(len(df)) - 2

degree = 5

order = degree + 1

n = order + k

t = np.zeros(math.ceil(len(df)/60) + (2*order)  # create an array to store knots.

t[:order] = 0

t[-:order] = len(df)

t[order:-order] = (breaks)

xx = np.arange(len(df))

for i in range(0,n):

```
c = np.zeros(n)
c[i] = 1
spl = BSpline(t,c,degree)
plt.plot(xx, spl(xx))
```

plt.show()

**With the python code above I get the plot:**

[image]

For my python code, I will like to have all the BSplines in a single object and not just be able to plot each BSpline one at a time. My goal is to use the full set of BSplines and it to pass it into another function to perform smoothing.

Basically, I am trying to follow the steps below but using Python:

[image]

Comment: will you provide a sample of your data?  I want to run it against my function